# Does Django syncdb sync edited models?

Tags: django, django-models

I have come across an interesting problem. I first created a model. And syncdb'ed it. Later on I changed the model by adding one models.DateField() and a models.DateTime(). Than I re syncdb'ed it... However the when I checked the database the rows were not added. Is this normal behaviour or did I do something wrong? Later on I deleted all tables and syncdb'ed and got all rows with no problems.

Comment: Django syncdb would only help you to get the initial schema design. It can not make the alteration provided later on. Try using Django South to do this for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the docs are quite explicit that it [does not alter existing tables](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/django-admin/#syncdb).

Use something like [South](http://south.aeracode.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Django itself doesn't support db migrations. You will need to look into [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) for this.

[This is a good place to start.](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part1.html)